# How to quantify tannin level in red wine?

Tags: red-wine

I just tasted a wine that has much silkier tannins than I've ever tasted before.  Is there a way to quantify the 'silkiness' of tannins in that wine vs another?  Is it the average length of the tannin molecule? Would I need a gas chromatography mass spectrometer or some kind of fancy piece of equipment?

How can I measure tannins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring Tannins in wine is a complicated process and needs a lot of chemical analysis in a laboratory. It can be done, but not within reach of your average person. Here is a snippet from a [pdf](https://www.awri.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/measuring-wine-tannins.pdf) on the subject:

> Wine total tannin: Tannins are a sub-class of phenolics that can
>   precipitate proteins. They contribute to wine texture, particularly
>   astringency. When grapes are crushed, the tannins present in grape
>   skin and seeds begin to be extracted into the grape must. Those from
>   skins tend to be more easily extracted than those from seeds. Once
>   extracted, the grape tannins begin to chemically rearrange, turning
>   into wine tannins, which can be significantly different in structure
>   from the original grape tannins. **Wine tannin concentration is reported
>   in g/L in epicatechin equivalents**.

A method to measure tannins in wine is called the MCP (methyl cellulose precipitable) tannin assay it is a simple and robust means of measuring
the total grape or wine tannin in red grape homogenate extracts, red wine, and other aqueous solutions.

You can find the convoluted procedures [here.](https://www.awri.com.au/wp-content/uploads/mcp_fact_sheet.pdf) It's really not as easy as they make it out to be.

Otherwise, it's a pretty subjective exercise. Each person perceives tannins differently. So, outside of a lab it's nearly impossible to quantify it.